# Weird graphical glitch in using winAPI to use color console

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I'm programming a little game in `C++` in the `console` for a school assignment. (Yes, being in console is required.)
I was using system("color 01") to pick an appropriate back and forecolor, but then I found a way to pick the color using the `winAPI`. Like so: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/Eyhv0pDG/

This works great, however it produces an odd `graphical glitch`. It `cout`s things one pixel to the left of where it should be. This gives me this unwanted behaviour when walking:

https://scontent-b-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/v/1508323_1421353738101215_634234870_n.jpg?oh=b3bacc821cb924a6aa84025c9ead310d&oe=52AE68C5

EDIT: When I minimize the window and reactive it, the glitched areas are gone?

---

**SOLUTION:** I was able to fix it by redrawing the window with invalidateRect()

Comment: maybe it has to do with the dithered fill characters you're using, as a kind of optical illusion? just guessing.

Comment: I don't think so, since it used to work before the colors, and it happens with text too, it cuts off the left row of pixels, but you barely notice that.